# How to handle Transaction Management by AOP

Tags: transactions, aop, spring-aop

I have read that AOP can be used for Logging ,Security,Transaction management.
even i have used AOP for logging in Spring boot Project .But i dont know how to use AOP for Transaction management .
Could anyone explain this with examples?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Basically the transaction principle in spring is based on Aop-proxy principle, To understand what happened, you must know the advisor and Intercepter principles, from the docs :

> An advisor is like a small self-contained aspect that has a single piece of advice.

Which mean when annotate your method with @Transactional you ask Spring to create proxy for your target service (AOP principle) and create [Around advice](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-ataspectj-around-advice)   to maintain transaction behavior which you can customize

This is a special kind of advisor  called transactional advice because it internally communicate with TransactionInterceptor as example , nothing special about it just it take care of transaction behaviour ( ready only , roolback ..)

> TransactionInterceptor delegate the actual transaction handling to a PlatformTransactionManager instance, which can be a HibernateTransactionManager (for a single Hibernate SessionFactory,

The use of transactional advice make possible to associate with the target methods a custom advisor and defining the order in which you want the advisors to be executed (after or before transactional advice)

Keep this overview and mind and here is some links To understand deeply  [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts-combining)  isan example how to turn service transactional by adding attribute to advisor

I highly recommend to check this [section](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#tx-decl-explained) in documentation to have complete view about what happened .